# Excel: How to search a row for a text value then return the column num of said value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a purely formula based solution in order to look for a text value within a single row. I want the formula to look to the left from my starting cell, until the text value is found, and then to return the column number of the cell with that text value.

I started thinking about using hlookup, or index(match), but this is not a defined range I am looking within, I want the formula to keep looking until it finds the text value rathe than search a specific range.

I just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Would the text value you're looking for sit in a cell on it's own or be part of a longer text string within the cell?

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it? The `MATCH` function would seem to be a good place to start.  Please also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and provide some examples.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The text value would sit in a cell on its own.

Comment: You can reference the entire row with the following syntax rownumber:rownumber e.g. 6:6, then you can search entire row.

Comment: Something like `=MATCH(A2,1:1,0)` should work where text value to search is in `Cell A2` and  `1:1` is the row in which value is to be searched.

Comment: As it's in a cell on its own then as @RonRosenfeld said - `Match` function is the way to go.  Look at the whole row as it's impossible to have any values outside that specific range.

Comment: Thank you all, that is very useful. I just realised a pertinent piece of information is that this text value occus multiple times in the row, and I only want to find the first occurance of the text value which appears to the left of the cell containing this formula.

Comment: **Please include an example as I mentioned in my previous comment.**

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Of course, i'm sorry, I'll get on that now.

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you. Your comments below my question did just enough to get my brain thinking in the right direction. This is the solution I have come up with.

`=MATCH("Baseline",INDIRECT("R106C"&MATCH(R105,105:105,0)&":R106C441",FALSE),0)`

This looks for the first occurance of the text "Baseline" within the row 106. The range column for this search starts with the first occurance on the row above (105) of the value in Cell R105 (which is the cell this formula is contained within). And the range ends at column 441 which is the end of the data.

Thank you!